# Microsoft Access list all database

Tags: c#

I need to fetch all databases of  `Microsoft Access` in `localhost`.

On clicking the database name I have to list the tables

I can able to fetch the tables for a particular database.

My problem is I cant able to list out the `MS Access` databases available in `localhost`
please suggest me the ideas to start coding

I tried

```
OleDbConnection con; // create connection 
OleDbCommand com; // create command     
OleDbDataReader dr; //Data read for read data from database 
con = new  OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =D:\mydb.mdb"); 
com = new  OleDbCommand("Select * from Table1",con); 
con.Open(); // open the connection dr =  com.ExecuteReader();
```

expected result:

with out mentioning `Data Source =D:\mydb.mdb"` i have to list all ms access databases of

```
localhost
```

All available databases like

```
database1.accdb
database2.accdb
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: As he said, he doesn't know where he has to begin. So it's obvious he is unable to provide you something he has tryed.

Answer (score 7):

Access (or Jet, to use the name of the database engine) doesn't run a server, in the way that Sql Server or MySql do.  An Access database is simply a file of particular format that is loaded on request, but the Jet engine libraries.

For this reason, there's no simple way to find all databases on a local machine: you would need to scan all files on the machine for `.accdb` or `.mdb` extensions.  More likely, you should ask the user to select a specific file or scan a specified subfolder, since searching the whole machine will likely take a prohibitively long time.

Comment: Is there a SQL command that retrieve the file name of mdb ?

Comment: In SQLite this is the SQL: `SELECT file FROM pragma_database_list WHERE name='main'` What is the same for Microsoft Access DB ?